# <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> when import pandas and sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, import, scikit-learn, xampp

I am working on a classifier using SVM. But I can't import pandas and sklearn modules. numpy and matplotlib.pyplot can be imported successfully however. The script saved in htdocs of XAMPP. Things I have tried:

- Anaconda installed completely. pandas and sklearn is listed in packages list. (I also created another environment for python 3.7, since I have both python 2.x and 3.x. Both of them contain pandas and sklearn).
- pandas and sklearn can be imported in terminal for both version.
- *#!/usr/bin/env python* is included. Browser execute my script without any issues except pandas import problem.

I received:[image]

Comment: I tried to add the package path as "sys.path.insert(0, "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages")". After that, the Pandas is able to be imported, but when I run method inside pandas, it returned more errors. For example if I run "df=pd.read_sql('Query', con=mydb)", it returned "df undefined, pd = <module 'pandas' from '/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc'>, pd.read_sql = <function read_sql>, con undefined, mydb = <mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object>" AND much more error message regarding the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and confirm pandas is there in one of those places

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I printed the path out. Not finding out Pandas and even Numpy. But I am sure numpy imported successfully.